# maya python ramp and texture thumbnail views in gui

Tags: python, maya

I am working on a python script for Maya and would like to use the small texture
thumbnails Maya displays for ramp textures, but in my script's GUI. Is there a way to utilize those images, or would I have to generate new thumbnails on the fly, as my script runs, and manage those images?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://help.autodesk.com/cloudhelp/2018/CHS/Maya-Tech-Docs/CommandsPython/show.html?swatchDisplayPort.html&cat=Windows

From the documentation above, I think you can use this command :

```
cmds.window()
cmds.columnLayout('r')
myShader = 'ramp2'
cmds.swatchDisplayPort('slPP', wh=(256, 256), sn=myShader)
cmds.showWindow()
```

If you are using PySide or PyQt, it is a bit tricky, you may have to use mayaAPI to find the pointer of this command.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
from sip import wrapinstance
import maya.cmds as cmds
import maya.OpenMayaUI as omui

def mayaToQT( name ):
    # Maya -> QWidget
    ptr = omui.MQtUtil.findControl( name )
    if ptr is None:         ptr = omui.MQtUtil.findLayout( name )
    if ptr is None:         ptr = omui.MQtUtil.findMenuItem( name )
    if ptr is not None:     return wrapinstance( long( ptr ), QtWidgets.QWidget )

myShader = 'ramp2'
control = cmds.swatchDisplayPort('slPP', wh=(256, 256), sn=myShader)

swatchQT_ramp2 = mayaToQT(control)
```

and then add to your pyside/pyqt this object converted back into your ui !